# Launch associated program or show "Open with" dialog from another program

Tags: java, windows, rundll32, shell32.dll

Under Window Seven, the following command displays a dialog box then terminates without any other action, why?

The expected effect is launching the associated program `Notepad++` or at least `Notepad`

```
RUNDLL32.EXE SHELL32.DLL,OpenAs_RunDLL D:\doc\toto.txt
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is very simple: `cmde.exe start`

Here is the Java code which embed the command:

```
private void open( File file ) {
   try {
      final String cmd =
         String.format( "cmd.exe /C start %s", file.getAbsolutePath());
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd );
   }
   catch( final Throwable t ) {
      t.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

When `.project` is selected the following dialog is shown:

[image]

and when the radio button at the bottom is chosen the following dialog is shown:

[image]

That's exactly what I want.

Comment: This won't work (i.e., won't display the "open with" dialog) for files that already have an associated application, such as the text file in your original example.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have updated the question's title which was unclear from the beginning...

Answer (score 8):

Firstly, note that `OpenAs_RunDLL` is an [undocumented entry point](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/11/26/270710.aspx#270867) so the only reason to expect it to work is that it appears in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT registry as an implementation for the `Open With` shell verb (in at least some versions of Windows).

This only means it can be expected to work *when called by the appropriate shell functions.* It does not mean it will necessarily work in any arbitrary context.

On my home machine (Windows Vista) calling `OpenAs_RunDLL` via `rundll32` works (i.e., the specified file is opened using the selected application) when the command is issued via the Start Menu's Run dialog, which can be opened with the keyboard shortcut `Windows+R`.

It does *not* work when issued from a command line console window, and the symptoms are the same as you describe: the dialog is presented, but the application is not launched.  This is perfectly legitimate behaviour, because you're using an undocumented entry point in a context it wasn't designed for.

Since there is no guarantee that `OpenAs_RunDLL` will exist at all in future versions of Windows, the upshot is simple: don't use it.  Use the supported [`SHOpenWithDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762234%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function instead, or use `ShellExecute` or `ShellExecuteEx` with the [`openas` verb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx); the latter may be particularly useful because it is [easy to do from a scripting language such as VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: According to various other answers elsewhere on Stack Overflow, the "openas" verb won't work if the "open" verb is available.  So `SHOpenWithDialog` may be the only reliable solution.

Comment: Can you give an example of a VBScript to use `SHOpenWithDialog`, please?

Comment: Can't be done from VBScript, as far as I know.  You would have to use a language that supports making calls to the Win32 API (such as C).

Answer (score 4):

Based on other answers to similar questions and on code from [CodeProject: Calling the Open With dialog box from your application, using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13103/Calling-the-Open-With-dialog-box-from-your-applica) and [PInvoke.net: SHOpenWithDialog (shell32)](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHOpenWithDialog.html) this is the code which works for me

```
ShellHelper.OpenAs(mainForm.Handle, "path/to/file")
```

both on Windows XP and on Windows Vista and later. This code uses only documented API (no `rundll32`)

```
public class ShellHelper
{
    #region http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHOpenWithDialog.html

    [DllImport("shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "SHOpenWithDialog", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int SHOpenWithDialog(IntPtr hWndParent, ref tagOPENASINFO oOAI);

    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773363(v=vs.85).aspx 
    private struct tagOPENASINFO
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string cszFile;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string cszClass;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public tagOPEN_AS_INFO_FLAGS oaifInFlags;
    }

    [Flags]
    private enum tagOPEN_AS_INFO_FLAGS
    {
        OAIF_ALLOW_REGISTRATION = 0x00000001,   // Show "Always" checkbox
        OAIF_REGISTER_EXT = 0x00000002,   // Perform registration when user hits OK
        OAIF_EXEC = 0x00000004,   // Exec file after registering
        OAIF_FORCE_REGISTRATION = 0x00000008,   // Force the checkbox to be registration
        OAIF_HIDE_REGISTRATION = 0x00000020,   // Vista+: Hide the "always use this file" checkbox
        OAIF_URL_PROTOCOL = 0x00000040,   // Vista+: cszFile is actually a URI scheme; show handlers for that scheme
        OAIF_FILE_IS_URI = 0x00000080    // Win8+: The location pointed to by the pcszFile parameter is given as a URI
    }

    private static void DoOpenFileWith(IntPtr hwndParent, string sFilename)
    {
        tagOPENASINFO oOAI = new tagOPENASINFO();
        oOAI.cszFile = sFilename;
        oOAI.cszClass = String.Empty;
        oOAI.oaifInFlags = tagOPEN_AS_INFO_FLAGS.OAIF_ALLOW_REGISTRATION | tagOPEN_AS_INFO_FLAGS.OAIF_EXEC;
        SHOpenWithDialog(hwndParent, ref oOAI);
    }

    #endregion

    #region http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13103/Calling-the-Open-With-dialog-box-from-your-applica

    [Serializable]
    private struct ShellExecuteInfo
    {
        public int Size;
        public uint Mask;
        public IntPtr hwnd;
        public string Verb;
        public string File;
        public string Parameters;
        public string Directory;
        public uint Show;
        public IntPtr InstApp;
        public IntPtr IDList;
        public string Class;
        public IntPtr hkeyClass;
        public uint HotKey;
        public IntPtr Icon;
        public IntPtr Monitor;
    }

    // Code For OpenWithDialog Box

    [DllImport("shell32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    extern private static bool ShellExecuteEx(ref ShellExecuteInfo lpExecInfo);

    private const uint SW_NORMAL = 1;

    private static void OpenAsOld(IntPtr hwndParent, string file)
    {
        ShellExecuteInfo sei = new ShellExecuteInfo();
        sei.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(sei);
        sei.Verb = "openas";
        sei.File = file;
        sei.Show = SW_NORMAL;
        sei.hwnd = hwndParent;
        if (!ShellExecuteEx(ref sei))
            throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();
    }

    #endregion

    public static void OpenAs(IntPtr hWndParent, string file)
    {
        if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 5)
        {
            DoOpenFileWith(hWndParent, file);
        }
        else
        {
            OpenAsOld(hWndParent, file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `ShellExecute` does not work for me (win10) unless `sei.fMask =  SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST` is set as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21182262/362515

Comment: While I found this quite helpful, this is a C# answer to a question tagged as Java. This answer should be migrated to the C# question [How can I show the “Open with” file dialog?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4726441/1497596).