# Win CLI open file with "How to open"?

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-console

I need to open the file using Windows 10 cmd. But when the file opens, I need Windows to show me a modal window "How do you want to open this file?". The system should do this even if it already has a program selected by default to open a certain type of file. Is it possible to do this?

*To clarify my problem:*

I need the console to run for example ".py" not through the standard `Python.File="C:\Windows\py.exe " "%L" %*`, and for example via VS Code. You might tell me about the VS Code CLI. But how to handle an event where the user will not have VS Code, but for example Pycharm, and the user will want to open it through it? That is why the question was posed in such a way that the user could choose through what to open the file already through the built-in modal window in Windows. In any case, I will be glad of any suggestion to solve my problem.

I tried to find something similar, but apart from the standard `start something.som` I didn't find it. And this is not a solution to the problem, because `start` starts the file in the program that is specified by default in the system. This program may not even be the one that the user ever chose later. I came across a similar question in Stackoverflow, where a person wanted to see which program was responsible for opening a file with a certain extension, where `assoc` and `ftype` were used, but they did not give the desired result.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand any of that, but your last paragraph seemed wrong. `Start "" "P:\athTo\DoodlPad.exe" "S:\omewhere\File.txt”` will open, (as long as it can do), `S:\omewhere\File.txt`, in the program, `P:\athTo\DoodlPad.exe`, even if the default program for opening that file type is something else.

Comment: @Compo Yes, it's true. But I need to open the file using the program that the user wants. Because I can't get all the paths to the programs on the user's PC and then filter them by file format, that they can open. However, if you know how it can be done, I would be glad to get it.

Comment: Obviously, you ask the end user which program they want, preferably ask them to provide its fully qualified absolute path, and then use it. Alternatively ask them for the name of the executable file, not program display name, then search the available drives for it, Then use the resulting fully qualified absolute path in the command. So what's the code problem you are having? It isn't that the start command doesn't work, it's that you do not know how to make it very simple for the end user, without making it very complicated for the coding task. My advice is to use a GUI dialog input, not CLI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I open the "Open with" GUI from console command on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70553187/how-do-i-open-the-open-with-gui-from-console-command-on-windows)